# How to Copy-Item to destination with regex folder?

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a file in a folder while matching a regex pattern like `*-user` (example directory name: v52-user)
How can I do this with `Copy-Item`?

Comment: Doesn't your file have an extension?  Try `(Get-ChildItem -Path 'PathWhereTheFileIs' -Filter '*-user' -File) | Copy-Item -Destination 'PathToCopyTo'` The `-Filter` parameter doesn't take regex. Why did you put that in your question's title?

Comment: Sorry I got the wording a little wrong
I want to copy a file (with known extension) inside a folder that has a name of *-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you can use the `-Filter` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` (no regex) like so:

```
# assuming the file has an extension '.txt'
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'PathWhereTheFileIs' -Filter '*-user.txt' -File) | Copy-Item -Destination 'PathToCopyTo'
```

If you really want to use regex, you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'PathWhereTheFileIs' -File | 
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '-user$' } | 
Copy-Item -Destination 'PathToCopyTo'
```

---

From your comments I gather you need to find a **folder** that matches the `*-user` pattern and that you know exactly which file you need to copy once the folder is found.

For that you can do:

```
$fileToCopy  = 'X:\somewhere\known_filename.txt'
$destination = Get-ChildItem -Path 'PathWhereTheFolderShouldBe' -Filter '*-user' -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($destination) { Copy-Item -Path $fileToCopy -Destination $destination.FullName }
else { Write-Host "Destination folder could not be found.." }
```

Or with regex:

```
$fileToCopy  = 'X:\somewhere\known_filename.txt'
$destination = Get-ChildItem -Path 'PathWhereTheFolderShouldBe' -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
               Where-Object { $_.Name -match '-user$' }
if ($destination) { Copy-Item -Path $fileToCopy -Destination $destination.FullName }
else { Write-Host "Destination folder could not be found.." }
```

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm not being clear here, English isn't my native language. I meant that I want to copy a file whose entire name with extension is already known to me, to a folder which has a name matching the pattern *-user. For example, I want to copy a file.txt inside the v83-user folder so I want to match the *-user pattern

Comment: @marky004 Aha, so you have a file like 'X:\somewhere\thefiletocopy.txt' and need to copy that to a folder with a name that ends with '-user'. The question then is how to find the folder I guess? But then... what if there are many folders with that name pattern? Just pick the first one?

Comment: No, actually that folder is already in a unique directory so that wouldn't be a problem, all I want is to match that filter to copy the item in that folder